# Gradle Build Can't Find testSrcDirs

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to run a Gradle build for an existing Java project, but I get the following error that appears to be unrelated to my project.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myProject:test'.
> Could not get unknown property 'testSrcDirs' for task ':myProject:test' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you land on this page searching for the testSrcDir exception, try updating the gradle clover plugin jar from 2.0.1 to [latest versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin).

If can't update the version you could also try the workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin/issues/76)

```
test {
    ext.testSrcDirs = project.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs
}
```

Comment: This is a really useful answer when you can't upgrade the version of Gradle, itself, in a legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that my project needed to be built with Gradle 2.x but I was using Gradle 3.x. Once I reverted my Gradle version, the build worked.